# OnClickListner not called on the whole View

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

On an Android application I am developing i got this situation.

In a Fragment there is a ListView that contains a list of customers (stored in instances of the *Customer_InputOld* class) using a customized ArrayAdapter (named *ArrayAdapter_ClientiInput*). The single row contains a ViewFlipper with two TextViews and seven nearly identical TextViews.

I put a ClickListner and a TouchListner in the Adapter, so on the click (and the touch) of a line the application make something. This works, except for the fact that these events are not triggered on the whole row.

Only the rough 80% of the row is "clickable", while the last textView does not respond to the listner.

Sincerely I don't know what code to post cause I have no idea where the problem could be: I tried to toast the View.getWidth() on the Click of the View itself, but actually the width is 1280 px, the entire device's width.

The single row is inflated with this *customer_row.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/customerLogo"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ABCDEF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="D"


        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="28pt" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FBBB"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_selected_done" />


</ViewFlipper>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ragioneSocialeViewList"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"

    android:singleLine="true"

    android:text="Dummy Customer"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/canaleViewList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ragioneSocialeViewList"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"


    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="Dummy type"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sollecitiViewList"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ragioneSocialeViewList"
    android:gravity="center"


    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tipoViewList"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sollecitiViewList"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="F/S"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailViewList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/telefonoViewList"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telefonoViewList"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="dummymail@gmail.com"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000"

    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/telefonoViewList"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tipoViewList"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="tel. 035424344"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ultimoOrdineViewList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/capitalViewFlipper"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emailViewList"
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="21/12/2012"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

While the Adapter Code is this:

```
public class ArrayAdapter_ClientiInput extends ArrayAdapter<CustomerInputOld> {

public EventLog.Event ImageTouched;
//public ListView customerListView;
private ArrayList<CustomerInputOld> list;
private Context context;

//this custom adapter receives an ArrayList of RowData objects.
//RowData is my class that represents the data for a single row and could be anything.
public ArrayAdapter_ClientiInput(Context context, int textViewResourceId,     ArrayList<CustomerInputOld> rowDataList) {
    //populate the local list with data.
    super(context, textViewResourceId, rowDataList);
    this.list = new ArrayList<CustomerInputOld>();
    this.list.addAll(rowDataList);
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //creating the ViewHolder we defined earlier.
    ViewHolder_CustomerRow holder = new ViewHolder_CustomerRow();

    //creating LayoutInflater for inflating the row layout.
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //inflating the row layout we defined earlier.
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customers_row, null);

    //setting the views into the ViewHolder.
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ragioneSocialeViewList);
    holder.capital = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customerLogo);
    holder.flipper = (ViewFlipper) convertView.findViewById(R.id.capitalViewFlipper);
    //holder.line = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_whole_row);

    holder.canale = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.canaleViewList);
    holder.solleciti = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sollecitiViewList);
    holder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emailViewList);
    holder.tipo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tipoViewList);
    holder.numero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.telefonoViewList);
    holder.ultimoOrdine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ultimoOrdineViewList);

    //define an onClickListener for the CheckBox.
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //      Toast.makeText(getContext(),Integer.toString(v.getWidth()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), CustomerDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", list.get(position).getCompany());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xFAAA);
            } else if ( e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                        e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                isSelected(position, v);
            }

            //Ritorno false per permettere anche al OnClickListener di agire..
            return false;
        }
    });


    holder.flipper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CustomerListFragment.onRowIconClicked(position, (RelativeLayout) v.getParent(), (ViewFlipper) v, context);
        }
    });


    //setting data into the the ViewHolder.
    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getCompany());

    holder.capital.setText(list.get(position).getCompany().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
    holder.capital.setBackgroundColor(list.get(position).getIconColor());

    holder.canale.setText(list.get(position).getChannel());
    holder.solleciti.setText(list.get(position).getReminders());
    if (Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getReminders()) >= 3)
        holder.solleciti.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
    holder.email.setText(list.get(position).getEmail());

    holder.numero.setText("tel. " + list.get(position).number);
    holder.ultimoOrdine.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("c d MMM ''yy").format(list.get(position).getLastOrderDate()));

    if (list.get(position).getInvoiceCustomer() == null) {
        if (list.get(position).getDeliveryCustomer() == null) {
            holder.tipo.setText("F/S");
        } else {
            holder.tipo.setText("F");
        }
    } else {
        holder.tipo.setText("S");
    }

    //modifiche nel caso in cui sia selezionato
    if ( isSelected(position,convertView) ) {
        holder.flipper.showNext();
    }

    //return the row view.
    return convertView;
}

private boolean isSelected(int position, View v){
    if (position == CustomerListFragment.customerSelected) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFE6C86F);
        return true;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want the whole row to be clickable, why don't you use an `onItemClickListener` for the listview?

Comment: and don't use ontouchlistener and onclistener for the same view, it's the conflict point.

Comment: @Gumbo: I did not use `onItemClickListener` simply because I didn't know it existed ^^' However I can't get it work.

'lvCustomers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long args) { 
...
}'

But the code inside is never accessed!

@VINILSATRASALA: Actually the do not conflict. I added the touch event this morning, but this bug is present since days. The point is that the Touch Listener returns false, so the Click Listner can proceed

Comment: @SimoneChelo try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the listviews xml, becuase if any of the listview's childs are focusable, the `onItemClick` won't be triggered.

Comment: @Gumbo, it worked (using the line you suggested on the view too) ...

But this didn't change anything, the row is still "80% clickable" =(

Comment: Found the bug! In the last TextView I put `android:capitalize="words"`, and that is an EditText's attribute, not Textview's! So when I clicked on the last "20%" of screen - coincidetially, that TextBox- tha app thinks that the click was on the TextView and not the line!
Roughly what @Gumbo said, " if any of the listview's childs are focusable, the onItemClick won't be triggered", well, it was in a state similar to focusable, I think! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

In the last TextView I put `android:capitalize="words"`, and that is an EditText's attribute, not Textview's! So when I clicked on the last "20%" of screen - coincidentally, that TextBox- tha app thinks that the click was on the TextView and not the line!